# Python xlrd fails on reading dates to create CSV only in SOME cases

Tags: python, excel, date, csv

I've created a XLS2CSV function using xlrd and I do not know exactly what column may be used for dates in the .xls input file.

The following code is working almost ok, but in some cases (and not always the same rows "fails" if you run it many times with the same input XLS file) e.g. instead of 02/07/2015 saves an integer as 47853 (I guess the way excel saves dates is numeric)

```
import xlrd, csv

def xls2csv(xlsfile, csvfile):
lines = 0
print "processing " + xlsfile
with xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfile, encoding_override="cp1252") as wb:
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    # or wb.sheet_by_name('name_of_the_sheet_here')
    with open(csvfile, 'wb') as f:
        c = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
        for r in range(sh.nrows):
            data = []
            for i in sh.row_values(r):
                print(i)
                if isinstance(i, unicode):
                    i = i.encode('utf8')
                else:
                    try:
                        if int(i) == i:
                            i = int(i)
                    except:
                        pass
                data.append(i)
            c.writerow(data)
            lines += 1
return lines
```

I am astonished by almost in all cases it is working ok creating CSV with dates using DD/MM/YYYY format but just in some cases take them as integer.

It is weired that sometimes the line
    print(i)
shows dates and sometimes numbers for the same column with the same exact value (at least I am seeing the same date in the Excel view)

copying some sample "print(i)" data for 3 rows

```
274152097
cuello valeria
274152097@hotmail.com
CUOTAENERO16
SOCIALCARD0116
390.0
CBU
321000115000260990
15/01/2016

273292535
del soto juana
273292535@hotmail.com
CUOTAENERO16
SOCIALCARD0116
350.0
CBU
020092581100001132
06/01/2016

273220457
chavez yudith
273220457@hotmail.com
CUOTAENERO16
SOCIALCARD0116
350.0
CBU
020091351100001132
42384.0
```

Comment: Such an irregular and non-reproducible problem is most likely not due to Python's behavior, but due to the actual encoding of the xls file, which may be concealed and implicitly munged by Excel. Some dates are coded as integers and others using a DD/MM/YYYY format.

Comment: As a typical M$ app, Excel likes to take your data, guess what it thinks the data means, and display that guess to you. Sometimes it will even save that guess when you save the file, modifying your xls without your knowledge. This could explain the irregular behavior you observed. Try exporting the xls to csv, open the csv in a basic text editor, and grep for the records you printed out here.

Comment: Considering that **42384.0** is equal to 15-Jan-2016 and that you already show a DMY of **15/01/2016** then I'd say you have a problem with DMY vs. MDY in the source data. btw, **47853** is 05-Jan-2031, not 02-Jul-2015; **42187** is 02-Jul-2015. Also, have you considered that some dates may actually be datetimes? If a time was part of the date then `int(i) != i`.

Comment: @Jeeped I checked that and source data are always in the same DMY format, and problem appears before `int(i)` just when reading `i` from `sh.row_values(r)`

Comment: You need to be more rigorous about types. When debugging, don't just print `x`, but rather print `repr(x)` and/or `type(x)`. If I had to guess, I'd say your Excel file sometimes contains *strings* such as `'15/01/2016'` and other times contains *dates* such as `42384.0`.

Comment: Better yet, use xlrd's built-in detection of **Excel's** types. There is a sheet method `cell_type`, as well as a cell attribute `ctype`. Use them! Read the [docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966) and the [tutorial](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf)! Use xlrd's built-in utility functions to convert Excel dates to Python dates, and from there, format them as desired before writing them to the CSV.

Comment: Thanks @JohnY reading docs I found: "Dates are not stored as a separate data type; they are stored as floating point numbers and you have to rely on (a) the "number format" applied to them in Excel and/or (b) knowing which cells are supposed to have dates in them. This module helps with (a) by inspecting the format that has been applied to each number cell; if it appears to be a date format, the cell is classified as a date rather than a number. Feedback on this feature, especially from non-English-speaking locales, would be appreciated."